# How to access the database in Middleware using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, middleware, asp.net-core-2.0

I wrote some middleware to log the request path and query in the database. I have two seperate models. One for logging and one business model. After trying a few things I came up with this:

```
public class LogMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly DbConnectionInfo _dbConnectionInfo;

    public LogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, DbConnectionInfo dbConnectionInfo)
    {
        _next = next;
        _dbConnectionInfo = dbConnectionInfo;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.OnStarting( async () =>
        {
            await WriteRequestToLog(httpContext);
        });
        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }

    private async Task WriteRequestToLog(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        using (var context = new MyLoggingModel(_dbConnectionInfo))
        {
            context.Log.Add(new Log
            {
                Path = request.Path,
                Query = request.QueryString.Value
            });
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}

public static class LogExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLog(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LogMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
public class MyLoggingModel : DbContext
{
    public MyLoggingModel(DbConnectionInfo connection)
        : base(connection.ConnectionString)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Log> Log { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see nothing special. It works, but not quite the way I would have wanted it to. The problem lies probably in EF6, not being threadsafe.

I started with this in Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        services.AddSingleton<ApplicationSettings>();

        services.AddSingleton(provider => new DbConnectionInfo { ConnectionString = provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationSettings>().ConnectionString });
        services.AddTransient<MyLoggingModel>();
        services.AddScoped<MyModel>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseLog();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

`MyLoggingModel` needs to be transient in order to let it work for the middleware. But this method immediately causes problems:

> System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use
>   'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed
>   before calling another method on this context. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I can assure you that I did add `await` everywhere. But that did not resolve this. If I remove the async part then I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The changes to the database were
>   committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the
>   object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state.
>   Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because
>   more than one entity of type 'MyLoggingModel.Log' have the same
>   primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are
>   unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured
>   correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the
>   Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the
>   'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or DatabaseGeneratedAttribute'
>   for Code First configuration.

That's why I came up with above code. I would have wanted to use dependency injection for the model. But I cannot make this to work. I also cannot find examples on accessing the database from middleware. So I get the feeling that I may be doing this in the wrong place.

My question: is there a way to make this work using dependency injection or am I not supposed to access the database in the middleware? And I wonder, would using EFCore make a difference?

-- update --

I tried moving the code to a seperate class and inject that:

```
public class RequestLog
{
    private readonly MyLoggingModel _context;

    public RequestLog(MyLoggingModel context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task WriteRequestToLog(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        _context.EventRequest.Add(new EventRequest
        {
            Path = request.Path,
            Query = request.QueryString.Value
        });
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

And in Startup:

```
services.AddTransient<RequestLog>();
```

And in the middelware:

```
public LogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, RequestLog requestLog)
```

But this doesn't make a difference with the original approach, same errors. The only thing that seems to work (besides the non-DI solution) is:

```
private async Task WriteRequestToLog(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var context = (MyLoggingModel)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyLoggingModel));
```

But I do not understand why this would be different.

Comment: Try to avoid creating the instance manually. you could consider accessing it via the request's services `httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyLoggingModel>()`

Comment: Also some design advice. Middleware should not be accessing the DbContext directly (IMO) you could consider encapsulating it behind a service abstraction and inject that into the middleware.

Comment: @Nkosi using the request's service seems to work. How is this different from injecting it in the constructor?

Comment: I just suggested a service locator ati-pattern because you said that the DI is not working. You probably have not configured the services and middleware correctly but there was not enough information in the question to verify how you configured the middleware and services.

Comment: That fact that getting the service directly via the provider works shows that the db context was probably registered correctly. Can you show how you register the middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider abstracting the db context behind a service or create one for the db context itself and used by the middleware.

```
public interface IMyLoggingModel : IDisposable {
    DbSet<Log> Log { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();

    //...other needed members.
}
```

and have the implementation derived from the abstraction.

```
public class MyLoggingModel : DbContext, IMyLoggingModel {
    public MyLoggingModel(DbConnectionInfo connection)
        : base(connection.ConnectionString) {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Log> Log { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

The service configurations appear to be done correctly. With my above suggestion it would need to update how the db context is registered.

```
services.AddTransient<IMyLoggingModel, MyLoggingModel>();
```

the middleware can either have the abstraction injected via constructor or directly injected into the `Invoke` method.

```
public class LogMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IMyLoggingModel db) {
        await WriteRequestToLog(context.Request, db);
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private async Task WriteRequestToLog(HttpRequest request, IMyLoggingModel db) {
        using (db) {
            db.Log.Add(new Log {
                Path = request.Path,
                Query = request.QueryString.Value
            });
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

If all else fails consider getting the context from the request's services, using it as a service locator.

```
public class LogMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        await WriteRequestToLog(context);
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private async Task WriteRequestToLog(HttpContext context) {
        var request = context.Request;
        using (var db = context.RequestServices.GetService<IMyLoggingModel>()) {
            db.Log.Add(new Log {
                Path = request.Path,
                Query = request.QueryString.Value
            });
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried several solutions and came to the conclusion that there are two things that had to be fixed. 1) I can't use 'httpContext.Response.OnStarting(async'. There are situations where the context is already disposed. 2) There is a difference between injecting in the constructor and injecting on invoke. I don't know why, but it seems that the context is 'out of sync'. The alternative is to get it from services. Abstracting it didn't make a difference, but is a good thing to do.

Comment: I have one question about your code. Do I need 'using (db)'? I thought that DI takes care of disposing.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yes the DI takes care of disposing what was created within its scope. I personally do it on non shared dependencies to make sure.